# How to extract an ID number from a string?

Tags: php, regex, substr, csv

How do I retrieve the middle value using regex or preg_match?

```
$str = 'fxs_124024574287414=base_domain=.example.com; datr=KWHazxXEIkldzBaVq_of--syv5; csrftoken=szcwad; ds_user_id=219132; mid=XN4bpAAEAAHOyBRR4V17xfbaosyN; sessionid=14811313756%12fasda%3A27; rur=VLL;'
```

How do I only get values ​​from `ds_user_id` using regex or `preg_match`?

Comment: Do you have to use regex? It might be easier to do with `explode()`. `$array = explode(';', $str);` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: what command should I do to get specific values? with explode()

Comment: A bit of a fudge - but converting it to a parameter string and then parse it will give you an array of values - `parse_str(str_replace("; ", "&", $str), $params);` and then `echo $params['ds_user_id'];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use preg_match to match `ds_user_id=`, then forget those matched characters with `\K`, then match one or more digits.  No capture groups, no lookarounds, no parsing all the key-value pairs, no exploding.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8EBmC))

```
$str = 'fxs_124024574287414=base_domain=.example.com; datr=KWHazxXEIkldzBaVq_of--syv5; csrftoken=szcwad; ds_user_id=219132; mid=XN4bpAAEAAHOyBRR4V17xfbaosyN; sessionid=14811313756%12fasda%3A27; rur=VLL;';
echo preg_match('~ds_user_id=\K\d+~', $str, $out) ? $out[0] : 'no match';
```

Output:

```
219132
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, nothing can beat the mickmackusa `\K` construct.
But, for the *\K* impaired engines, this is the next best thing

`(\d(?<=ds_user_id=\d)\d*)(?=;)`

Explained

```
 (                          # (1 start), Consume many ID digits
      \d                         # First digit of ID
      (?<= ds_user_id= \d )      # Look behind, assert ID key exists before digit
      \d*                        # Optional the rest of the digits
 )                          # (1 end)
 (?= ; )                    # Look ahead, assert a colon exists
```

---

This one is a verb solution (no \K), about %30 faster.

```
 (                             # (1 start), Consume many ID digits
      \d                            # First digit of ID
      (?:
           (?<! ds_user_id= \d )         # Look behind, if not ID,
           \d*                           # get rest of digits
           (*SKIP)                       # Fail, then start after this
           (?!)
        |  
           \d*                           # Rest of ID digits
      )
 )                             # (1 end)
 (?= ; )                       # Look ahead, assert a colon exists
```

---

Some benchmarks for comparison

```
Regex1:   (\d(?:(?<!ds_user_id=\d)\d*(*SKIP)(?!)|\d*))(?=;)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    0.53 s,   534.47 ms,   534473 µs
Matches per sec:   93,550


Regex2:   (\d(?<=ds_user_id=\d)\d*)(?=;)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    0.80 s,   796.97 ms,   796971 µs
Matches per sec:   62,737


Regex3:   ds_user_id=\K\d+(?=;)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    0.21 s,   214.55 ms,   214549 µs
Matches per sec:   233,046


Regex4:   ds_user_id=(\d+)(?=;)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    0.23 s,   231.23 ms,   231233 µs
Matches per sec:   216,232
```

Comment: I know that you are better than this post.  Is someone else posting answers with your account?

Comment: You are looking both ways every time a sequence of digits is encountered.

Comment: (There's the sln that I expect.)

Answer (score 0):

If we wish to use `explode`:

```
$str = 'fxs_124024574287414=base_domain=.example.com; datr=KWHazxXEIkldzBaVq_of--syv5; csrftoken=szcwad; ds_user_id=219132; mid=XN4bpAAEAAHOyBRR4V17xfbaosyN; sessionid=14811313756%12fasda%3A27; rur=VLL;';

$arr = explode(';', $str);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/ds_user_id/s', $value)) {
        $ds_user_id = explode('=', $value);
        echo $ds_user_id[1];
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
219132
```

---

Here, we can also use two non-capturing groups with a capturing group:

```
(?:ds_user_id=)(.+?)(?:;)
```

where we have a left boundary:

```
(?:ds_user_id=)
```

and a right boundary:

```
(?:;)
```

and we collect our desired digits or anything else that we wish to have using:

```
(.+?)
```

---

If we wish to validate our ID number, we can use:

```
(?:ds_user_id=)([0-9]+?)(?:;)
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/28sFkE/1)

and our desired value can be simply called using `var_dump($matches[0][1]);`.

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?:ds_user_id=)(.+?)(?:;)/m';
$str = 'fxs_124024574287414=base_domain=.example.com; datr=KWHazxXEIkldzBaVq_of--syv5; csrftoken=szcwad; ds_user_id=219132; mid=XN4bpAAEAAHOyBRR4V17xfbaosyN; sessionid=14811313756%12fasda%3A27; rur=VLL;';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "ds_user_id=219132;"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "219132"
  }
}
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/OmDEIJ/1/)

Comment: Please require posters to "try something" before you answer.  When this community is abused as a free code writing service, more "give me the codez" questions are encouraged.  Furthermore, when ever a regex pattern's return value needs to be exploded, the pattern should be refined instead.

Comment: Quote block formatting is for quoted text.  On Stackexchange sites, quote formatting is typically used on error messages and exact quotes from documentation.

Comment: See my answer for how simply this task can be written.